# Renderer troubles with SDL2 and Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, sdl

I try to write something in C with SDL2 but I have some troubles with the renderer.

My code is:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "main.h"

#define WND_WIDTH   800
#define WND_HEIGHT  600

void displayText(SDL_Renderer *rdr,TTF_Font *font,char *str,SDL_Color *color,SDL_Rect *text_coo) 

{
SDL_Surface *text=TTF_RenderText_Blended(font,str,*color);
SDL_Texture *tx_text=SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rdr,text);
SDL_QueryTexture(tx_text,NULL,NULL,&text_coo->w,&text_coo->h);
text_coo->x=(WND_WIDTH-text_coo->w)/2;
text_coo->y=(WND_HEIGHT-text_coo->h)/2;
SDL_RenderCopy(rdr,tx_text,NULL,text_coo);
SDL_RenderPresent(rdr);
SDL_DestroyTexture(tx_text);
SDL_FreeSurface(text);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
  SDL_Window *wnd;
  SDL_Renderer *rdr;
  SDL_Rect text_coo;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  TTF_Init();
  TTF_Font *font=TTF_OpenFont("/Users/coldpe/Documents/SDLProject2/SDLProject/Batang.ttf",24);
         wnd=SDL_CreateWindow("Noname",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,WND_WIDTH,WND_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);

rdr=SDL_CreateRenderer(wnd,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_ShowWindow(wnd);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,64,64,64,0xff);
SDL_RenderClear(rdr);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,128,128,128,0xff);
SDL_Rect r={WND_WIDTH/2-100,WND_HEIGHT/2-100,200,200};
SDL_RenderFillRect(rdr,&r);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,64,64,64,0xff);

SDL_Color normal_color={0,0,255,0xff};
SDL_Color selected_color={0,255,0,0xff};
SDL_Color *pc=&normal_color;
displayText(rdr,font,"Hello",pc,&text_coo);
bool done=false;

while(!done) {
    SDL_Event event;
    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {

        if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
            done=true;

        if(event.type==SDL_MOUSEMOTION) 
{
            if(event.motion.x>=text_coo.x && event.motion.x<=text_coo.x+text_coo.w &&
               event.motion.y>=text_coo.y && event.motion.y<=text_coo.y+text_coo.h) {
                if(pc!=&selected_color) {
                    pc=&selected_color;
                    displayText(rdr,font,"Hello",pc,&text_coo);
                }
            }
            else
                if(pc!=&normal_color) {
                    pc=&normal_color;
                    displayText(rdr,font,"Hello",pc,&text_coo);
                }
        }
    }
}

SDL_DestroyRenderer(rdr);
SDL_DestroyWindow(wnd);
TTF_CloseFont(font);
TTF_Quit();
SDL_Quit();

return(0);
}
```

I already tried to ask for help in other forum's website, and I should obtain this image with mouse not in the text :

[image: Mouse not on the text]

And this image with mouse on the text :

[image: Mouse on the text]

But, for a reason that I don't know, here is the image I really obtain with mouse not on the text :

[image: Mouse not on the text]

And here is the result I obtain with mouse on the text :

[image: Mouse on the text]

Why when the mouse is on the text, the "background" is black ?

I'm sure that it is not a code's trouble because this code works with some other peoples...
For your information, I'm in Xcode 9 (Xcode 10 have some bugs with OpenGL).

Someone have answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you clear backbuffer with desired color only once. When next frame is rendered old backbuffer content is gone so you need to redraw it again. That is `displayText` should start with

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,64,64,64,0xff);
SDL_RenderClear(rdr);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,128,128,128,0xff);
SDL_Rect r={WND_WIDTH/2-100,WND_HEIGHT/2-100,200,200};
SDL_RenderFillRect(rdr,&r);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rdr,64,64,64,0xff);
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. But, this code is a very short "test" code. With this code I want to just "redraw" a part of the screen. I tried it an other program with longer code, and I had this problem. So your solution works great, but I don't want to clear the screen and "redraw" everything because here there is not so much thing to redraw, but with a more complicated code, that will be painful. I'm not sure I'm very clear but for sum up I want to redraw just a part of the screen (like in a game, a dialogue's box or the menu's box "above" the game).

Comment: @Coldpe Then you can render to texture and then copy that texture to back buffer.

Comment: Yes, I think it's the "less worst" solutions. SDL's doc tells about SDL_RenderPresent  : "The backbuffer should be considered invalidated after each present". I think it's the reason why I should not proceed the way I wanted. Thanks for your help !